# linuxの/var/mailの意味を知りたい

Tags: mail

こんばんは。

linuxのcent osサーバーで、私が作っていないのでわからないんですが、
例えばuserで「hogehoge_m」というユーザーがいた場合に
/var/mailに「hogehoge_m」が入っています。

メールを送れたりするのでしょうか？qmail使っているようです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/var/mail` は `filesystem` パッケージに含まれています。

このパッケージの説明によると Linux OS における基本的なディレクトリ構成なのでディレクトリ自体はデフォルトで存在する感じです。

> The basic directory layout for a Linux system
>   The filesystem package is one of the basic packages that is installed on a Linux system. Filesystem contains the basic directory layout for a Linux operating system, including the correct permissions for the directories.

で、何に使っているかと言うと、Linuxのメールシステムでは、OSユーザ間でのメールのやりとりが可能です。`/var/mail/ユーザ名` がユーザのメールボックスになります。`mail` `mailx` などのコマンドで メールを送受信できます。また、システムがroot宛にメッセージを送信することもあります。

また、SMTP,POP3,IMAP などのいわゆる「メールサーバー」は、それぞれ専用のサーバーソフトを導入すれば利用可能です。その場合も（設定次第ですが）`/var/mail/ユーザ名` に受信メールのデータが格納されます。